# Ford v6 leaking transmission fluid between engine and torque converter

Tags: ford, transmission, leak, seal, shaft

2011 ford taurus v6 auto trans 100k miles. Got stuck im the snow and was spinning tires trying to get unstuck. wheels stopped turning so shut it down and walked. When i went back and pulled it out with a 4wd there was a large pool of trasnsmission fluid under the engine/transmission. Took it to a local garage and the guy jacked it up and crawled under and said the leak was between engine and torque converter probably shaft seal. Beyond their capability, get rid of car, repair cost over 2500$. Clearly it was caused by me so lets talk about the repair..what should i do next? Nearest transmission shop is 60 miles. Try an additive, add fluid and see if it leaks out, small dab of c4? I dont have alot tied up in the car so it wouldnt kill me to just walk away but on the other hand it is or was a pretty good car, rusty but straight, engine runs good, uses no oil.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I feel your pain, the only thing is that you're asking for opinions which is off topic on stack exchange sites as there won't be fact based answers. We can only say what we'd do instead of what you should do. If you have the tools and want to give it a shot you could replace it with a used one from a salvage yard, if not then it's entirely a cost-benefit between repair or a new car.

Comment: Insurance companies consider a car written off when the cost of repairs is more than 50-70% of the car's resale value (depends on the company), this is because any extra things found can increase the costs of the repair above the value of the car. I see no reason to argue with them on this.

Comment: You may have overheated your transmission fluid.  The seal may have leaked under the stress.  I would try adding fluid, rather than immediately giving up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Front trans seal. That was a very common problem years ago. Usually requires removal of trans but no internal work on the trans. It was not unusual to just add trans oil as needed if the car was not very valuable.